# Prevent multiple calls to refresh session in express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0

I am currently working on an expressjs application which manages the session for a bunch of micro services. I want to run middleware on all requests that will handle any necessary refresh_token logic before the request is then passed on to the micro service.

The issue I have is that when the requests happen in parallel they all attempt to handle the refresh_token, which causes some of the requests to blow-up.

I realise I can handle the logic in the clientside application through an axios interceptor or similar, but the api is used by multiple clients so I would prefer to handle centrally.

Currently my thoughts are something like this:

```
const refreshTokenPromise = {};
function enqueueRefreshToken(refreshToken) {
  if (refreshTokenPromise[refreshToken]) {
    refreshTokenPromise[refreshToken].listeners = refreshTokenPromise[refreshToken].listeners + 1;
  } else {
    refreshTokenPromise[refreshToken] = {
      promise: axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${authServiceHostname}/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=${refreshToken}`,
        timeout: 30000,
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: {}
      }),
      listeners: 1
    };
  }
  return refreshTokenPromise[refreshToken];
}

function dequeueRefreshToken(refreshToken) {
  if (refreshTokenPromise[refreshToken].listeners > 1) {
    refreshTokenPromise[refreshToken].listeners = refreshTokenPromise[refreshToken].listeners - 1;
    return;
  }

  delete refreshTokenPromise[refreshToken];
}
```

This feels a bit too much like a hack, it also wouldn't solve the issue when the app runs in a cluster.

Does anyone know of a more robust solution to solve the issue?